# Full Calendar - next prev button events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar with events generated from a json file. What i want to do is to show list of events in a month when user clicks next or prev button using full calendar plugin. I tried to achieve but when i click next and prev button it doesn't shows the events. I need to show events according to months

Comment: If your JSON events include `start` values, as they must, this will work automatically.  If it is not working, you have a problem in your code, and you'll need to show us a *minimal* version of your code and your JSON.

Comment: As Don't Panic said, what you're describing is exactly how the calendar is supposed to work. Probably you did something wrong in your implementation, but we can't say what because you haven't shown us your code or your JSON. If you edit the question to include it you may be able to get some help.

Comment: Tahnk you for your answer. finally i found a solution for it